# php, convert to hexadecimal integer

Tags: php, colors, hex

My `$_POST` value contains css friendly hex color value, for example: `#ffffff`. In order to make it friendly towards the [ColorJizz](http://code.google.com/p/colorjizz/) library, I should have it in hexadecimal integer value. The code below doesn't work. If I replace the `$color_hex` variable with a hard coded value for example: `0xffffff`, it works.

```
include('colorjizz.php');   
$color_hex = '0x' . substr($_POST['color'], 1); 
$color = new Hex($color_hex);
```

This is most likely a very noob level problem, but after hitting my head to the wall for a quite few hours, I'd be grateful for any advice. Thank you.

Comment: ColorJizz may be hosted on code.google.com, but it is not "Google's" package.

Comment: Can you put `(int)` at the front?

Comment: What is the actual output of `$color_hex` in this example? I can't see an issue with it, assuming you are indeed getting a valid 6 digit hex value for `$_POST['color']`, WITH the # number sign character.

Comment: Hi Madmartigan, thanks for the reply. The actual $color_hex output in this example could be for example "0xFFFFFF" when the $_POST['color'] value has been #FFFFFF. Unfortunately ColorJizz doesn't like to work with it, most likely due to a wrong data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hexadecimal integer value" doesn't make much sense. Hex is a representation of a number (thus a string), while integer value speaks of the machine format of a number.

If you want the number, a quick Google search found [`hexdec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php)

```
$color = hexdec(substr($_POST['color'], 1));
```

It appears to ignore leading "junk", so you could even use

```
$color = hexdec($_POST['color']);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ikegami. And oh, I had tried the hexdec method, but since it didn't output a value with a preceding "0x", for example "0xFFFFFF" I though it doesn't fit. But it sure does accept it. And it works with this now. Great! Thank you.

Comment: @Tuomas, `0xFFFFFF` is a numeric *literal* (a piece of the *code*) that produces the number 16,777,215. `hexdec('FFFFFF')` is another piece of code that produces the same number. Having the string `0xFFFFFF` in a *variable* is much different than having `0xFFFFFF` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you **have** a string containing a hexadecimal representation of a number and you want to have it as a integer you have to convert from hex to dec. If I get your question right.

```
$dec = hexdec("ff0000");
```

http://php.net/hexdec

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, the data type for a hexadecimal integer and a decimal integer is the same; being able to type `0xDEAD` in your source code is just syntactic sugar. Thus, you can use [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to convert the form input to a normal PHP integer from a string:

```
$color_hex = intval(substr($_POST['color'], 1), 16);
```

The final parameter, `16`, specifies that the input string is in hexadecimal.